# A game of some consequence

Tags: knowledge, pattern, word-property, connect-wall, pencil-and-paper-games

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #3: Pencil and Paper Games](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7388/)</sub>

---

Last night, I played a game of [Consequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consequences_(game)) with seven friends. In our particular version of the rules*, a game consists of eight rounds:

> 1. His name;
> 2. (met) Her name;
> 3. Where they met;
> 4. He wore...
> 5. She wore...
> 6. He said...
> 7. She said...
> 8. And the consequence was...

As per the usual gameplay each player simultaneously took a piece of paper, wrote their answer for the current round, folded the paper down to hide their answer, then passed it to the player on their left. Play then continued until the final round was written, and the papers passed one final time. Each player then read aloud the answers on their sheet, sometimes with hilarity ensuing (it's not guaranteed in some circles...).

For example, the sheet I read out had been completed as follows:

> Ernest Hemingway
>
> (*met*) Rebecca Adlington
>
> Within the Super User Stack Exchange.
>
> (*He wore*) Decent, sturdy footwear and a sensible suit.
>
> (*She wore*) Nothing.
>
> (*He said*) "They kicked me off the boat - I was absolutely livid!"
>
> (*She said*) "I'll bet you shouted 'til your voice was hoarse!"
>
> (*And the consequence was...*) To round off the evening nicely they shared a bottle of wine and fell asleep in each other's arms.

(I can only apologise for some of my friends' lewdness and poor idea of 'humour', but this tends to be the way the game goes...)

Anyway, to make the game more interesting, before starting we had each drawn out of a hat a secret 'construction challenge' which we had to employ while coming up with our answers - some kind of pattern that we had to apply consistently to everything we wrote. For example, one of the unused challenges that remained in the hat was to conceal the name of a colour among each answer.

My challenge to you is:

> **Given the other answers from last night's game, (below, in alphabetical order by round) can you reconstruct what each of the other seven sheets of paper looked like at the end of the night (clockwise from me), and explain each of our 'construction challenges'?**

(Coincidentally, it also turns out there was one round where everybody clearly cheated at the same time and had a peek at the answer immediately previous, so they could write the next part for humorous effect! I'm sure you'll spot where...)

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **His name** | Hugh Hefner | Jamie Foxx | Marty McFly | Sepp Blatter | Seve Ballesteros | Tim Nice-But-Dim | Zayn Malik |
| **Her name** | A nymph from Greek mythology | Bea Arthur | Elven beauty, Arwen Undómiel | Jane Eyre | Lizzo | Perrie Edwards, from Little Mix | Wonder Woman |
| **Where they met** | A country in South Asia | A private plane | Belgium | In a very grand hotel | On the deck of the Starship Enterprise | The back seat of a Honda Civic | While playing on the golf links |
| **He wore** | A Hawaiian shirt that was particularly vivid | A king's crown and signet ring | A school blazer, grey trousers, a tie, and smart shoes | An outfit straight out of *The Rocky Horror Picture Show* | Batman Cufflinks | Decorators' painting overalls | Tree decorations: Tinsel, baubles, and a star on top |
| **She wore** | A discreetly concealed earpiece and mic | A scuba diving suit | Flowers in her hair | Fur - and a coat of red paint from the protesters she encountered on the way | Junkyard chic | Sequins that shimmered in the moonlight | Something shiny you might see at the Academy Awards |
| **He said** | Babe, I'm as famous as The Artist Formerly Known as Prince | Bourbon? | I'm very into Shakespeare - I just adore "Much Ado About Nothing" | I've peed my pants! | May I have this dance? | My dear, let us run away to South America | Oh, fiddlesticks |
| **She said** | I prefer Red Bull - it gives you wings! | I'm actually quite well known myself - I'm on a couple of banknotes back home... | "Julius Caesar" is vastly superior | Never! | Oh, well done! | Si, señor - me gusta mucho | Watch your language - keep your tongue civil! |
| **And the consequence was...** | A hospital procedure to check for broken bones | Marriage! Then they had seventeen children and they all lived happily ever after in a giant shoe. | Naughtiness! | They both died in a plane crash | They both got food poisoning and were horribly ill | They exchanged a hug and a kiss then parted, never to speak again | They had to flee the country! |

<sup>* Note from OP: This is the base rule-set I've always played among friends. As we grew up, when we started to find the game a bit repetitive, we actually introduced a ninth bonus round to be played just before the final consequence, and which varied from game to game, chosen on the night by suggestions shouted out by the players, and which could end up being almost *anything*. Never, though, did we ever play with 'construction challenges' like this - I might suggest it next time we play...</sup>

<sup>PS No disrespect or besmirching of reputations is intended by the use of many real celebrities' names in this puzzle.</sup>

Comment: Thought I'd squeeze one more in before midnight :)

Comment: The "What is a Consequential Phrase™" Connect Wall – brilliant! I wonder why this hasn't been recieved better vote-wise, given that pattern puzzles are quite popular.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's call the players **S**(tiv), **T**, **U**, **V**, **W**, **X**, **Y**, and **Z**, in the order that their answers are on Stiv's sheet.

Below are the lists that each player ended up with at the end of the night, in clockwise order beginning with Stiv. Each player's answers are in their corresponding color.

> [image]

---

## Construction Challenges

Challenge for **S**tiv, found by cap:

> Each answer must describe a letter of the NATO phonetic alphabet.
>
> - *Ernest Hemingway* was nicknamed **PAPA**
> - *A nymph from Greek mythology* could be **ECHO**
> - *A country in South Asia* is **INDIA**
> - *A school blazer, grey trousers, a tie, and smart shoes* would be considered a **UNIFORM**
> - *Something shiny you might see at the Academy Awards* is **OSCAR**
> - *Bourbon?* = **WHISKEY**
> - *Oh, well done!* = **BRAVO**
> - *A hospital procedure to check for broken bones* = **X-RAY**

Challenge for person **T**:

> Each answer must include the title of a Best Picture Winner.
>
> - **Marty** McFly (1955)
> - **Rebecca** Adlington (1940)
> - In a very **grand hotel** (1931/32)
> - An outfit straight out of *The **Rocky** Horror Picture Show* (1976)
> - Sequins that shimmered in the **moonlight** (2016)
> - "Babe, I'm as famous as **The Artist** Formerly Known as Prince" (2011)
> - "I prefer Red Bull - it gives you **wings**!" (1927/28)
> - They both died in a plane **crash** (2005)

Challenge for person **U**:

> Each answer must conceal the name of a country.
>
> - Zayn **Mali**k (Mali)
> - Wonder W**oman** (Oman)
> - Within the Su**per U**ser Stack Exchange. (Peru)
> - Decorator**s' pain**ting overalls (Spain)
> - A s**cuba** diving suit (Cuba)
> - "I'm very into Shakespeare - I just adore 'Mu**ch Ad**o About Nothing'" (Chad)
> - "I'm actually quite well known myself - I'**m on a co**uple of banknotes back home…" (Monaco)
> - They exchanged a h**ug and a** kiss then parted, never to speak again (Uganda)

Challenge for person **V**, found by cap:

> Each answer must begin with the three-letter abbreviation for a month.
>
> - **Sep**p Blatter
> - **Jan**e Eyre
> - **A pr**ivate plane
> - **Dec**ent, sturdy footwear and a sensible suit.
> - **Jun**kyard chic
> - "**May** I have this dance?"
> - "'**Jul**ius Caesar' is vastly superior"
> - **Mar**riage! Then they had seventeen children and they all lived happily ever after in a giant shoe.

Challenge for person **W**, based on cap's answer:

> Each word must begin with the symbols for successive elements of the periodic table, starting with H for hydrogen and continuing through all eight answers.
>
> - **H**ugh **He**fner
> - **Li**zzo
> - **Be**lgium
> - **B**atman **C**ufflinks
> - **N**othing
> - "**O**h, **f**iddlesticks"
> - "**Ne**ver!"
> - **Na**ughtiness!

Challenge for person **X**:

> Each answer's last word (thanks, Stiv) consisting entirely of valid Roman numerals. (appropriate given that they're person X)
>
> - Tim Nice-But-**Dim**
> - Perrie Edwards, from Little **Mix**
> - The back seat of a Honda **Civic**
> - A Hawaiian shirt that was particularly **vivid**
> - A discreetly concealed earpiece and **mic**
> - "They kicked me off the boat - I was absolutely **livid**!
> - "Watch your language - keep your tongue **civil**!"
> - They both got food poisoning and were horribly **ill**.

Challenge for person **Y**:

> Each answer must include a word which sounds the same (homophone) as a word for an animal.
>
> - Jamie **Foxx** (fox)
> - **Bea** Arthur (bee)
> - While playing on the golf **links** (lynx)
> - A king's crown and **signet** ring (cygnet)
> - Flowers in her **hair** (hare)
> - "My **dear**, let us run away to South America" (deer)
> - "I'll bet you shouted 'til your voice was **hoarse**!" (horse)
> - They had to **flee** the country! (flea)

Challenge for person **Z**:

> Each answer's first word is a one-word number with one letter removed.
>
> - **Seve** Ballesteros (7)
> - **Elven** beauty, Arwen Undómiel (11)
> - **On** the deck of the Starship Enterprise (1)
> - **Tree** decorations... (3)
> - **Fur** - and a coat of red paint... (4)
> - **I've** peed my pants! (5)
> - **Si**, señor... (6)
> - **To** round off the evening (2)

Comment: Not just *any* word though - a particular one :) This one is correct. Keep going and see if you can find some more!

Comment: Nice! For the last one I'm seeing rot13(ZNYV, BZNA, CREH, ? PHON, PUNQ, ZBANPB, HTNAQN)

Comment: Lol you beat me to it.

Comment: Great work - you got all of it in the end :) Well done +1 and a checkmark on the way...

Answer (score 4):

Also partial, not repeating the two challenges found by @stewartIM and using the same nomenclature,

Stiv's challenge is

> the answer describes a letter of the [NATO Phonetic Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet):
>
> - *Ernest Hemingway* was nicknamed **PAPA**
> - *A nymph from Greek mythology* could be **ECHO**
> - *A country in South Asia* is **INDIA**
> - for *he wore* there are two answers that could describe **UNIFORM**
> - *Something shiny you might see at the Academy Awards* is **OSCAR**
> - *Bourbon?* **WHISKEY**
> - *Oh, well done!* **BRAVO**
> - *A hospital procedure to check for broken bones* **X-RAY**

and V's challenge is

> the answer must start with the first three letters of a month:
>
> - *his name* could be ***Mar**ty McFly* or ***Sep**p Blatter* (although probably the latter because March appears in another answer)
> - ***Jan**e Eyre*
> - ***A pr**ivate plane*
> - ***Dec**ent, sturdy footwear and a sensible suit* (there is another answer starting with Dec but given the answers in the first complete example, it must be this one that belonged to that challenge)
> - ***Jun**kyard chic*
> - ***May** I have this dance?*
> - *"**Jul**ius Caesar" is vastly superior*
> - ***Mar**riage! Then they had seventeen children and they all lived happily ever after in a giant shoe.*

incomplete idea for another challenge

> Every word starts with an elemental symbol (maybe has to be 2 letters, not sure):
>
> - ***Se**ve **Ba**llesteros* (***H**ugh **He**fner* could also work if single letter symbols are allowed. ***Er**nest **He**mmingway* also works but I believe he was part of a different challenge.)
> - ***Li**zzo* (***Be**a **Ar**thur* also works but she was part of a different challenge)
> - ***Be**lgium*
> - the most conspicuous one here: ***Ba**tman **Cu**fflinks*
> - ***No**thing*
> - *he said* is where this idea breaks down. ***B**ourbon?* would have worked as a single letter symbol, but I believe the answer here is *Oh, fiddlesticks* where O could be a symbol but fiddlesticks...
> - ***Ne**ver!* (this dialog answer is even in the correct place)
> - ***Na**ughtiness!*

Comment: Great! Your answer for V's "she wore" overlaps with my answer for Y, but I found another match

Comment: Nice work - a good contribution and you were very close with your third suggestion too +1